# I want to run DNS server, but ports 53 and 5353 are blocked by ISP

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I want to run DNS server, but ports 53 and 5353 are blocked by ISP. All other ports are open, but not 53 and 5353.

Comment: If you want to run a DNS server *for the Internet* on the public IP provided by your ISP, you have to ask your ISP to unblock TCP/UDP 53. (Also, you have to be sure that you are not behind CGNAT.)

Comment: I have public IP, also asked to ISP to open  53 and 5353 port but  they are taking some time to answer. In case ISP deny to provide that port then I have to buy domain I knw. Is any other solution available.

Comment: I do not know your exact reason of running a public DNS server. But I guess it needs to be running on 7x24 basis. For such a need, renting a **VPS server** may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Nameservers come in (broadly speaking) 2 types - authorative - which you can use to publish information about your domains to the world and require external access to port 53 and recursive, which help clients on your network resolve DNS - and do not require to be reached externally on port 53.

Buying or not buying a domain name has nothing to do with bypassing problems on port 53. Most domain name providers provide free authorative DNS for domain provided through them whuch may aleviate the need to run nameservers.  This is generally beneficial as you really should have a minimum of 2 nameservers on different IPs, and an ISP only provides 1.

If you need to get arround the ISP blocking port 53 a VPN provider who offers static IPs will bypass this limit, but setting up a couple of virtual machines is likely more robust.